# SQL Server Polybase create external table ERROR to Oracle with column datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes, external-tables, sql-server-2019, polybase

Created database scoped credential and an external datasource to Oracle OK.
Creating external table on Orcle table with a column datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE fails no matter what datatype I try to use.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYSCHEMA.MY_EXT_TABLE
(
    SOMECOL NVARCHAR(21) COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_BIN, -- OK
    SOME_DATETIME DATETIME2,    -- OK
    SOME_DATE_COMM DATE,-- OK
    SOME_FLOAT float,-- OK

    SOME_TIMESTAMP datetimeoffset(7)  -- NOK
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = N'ORACLEDATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE',
    DATA_SOURCE = my_oracle_ds
)
GO
```

Fails with error:
Msg 105083, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
105083;The following columns in the user defined schema are incompatible with the external table schema for table 'SOME_TABLE': 'SOME_TIMESTAMP' failed to be reflected with the error: 'The detected backend type TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE is not supported for external generic tables.'

I tried with datetime, datetime2, datetimeoffset, NVARCHAR but the same error occurs.
Is there a workaround for polybase/generic tables or do I have to skip these columns?

Comment: It says in the error that it isn't supported. You could try creating a view in Oracle that converts it to date or varchar and reference the view instead.

Comment: Yes in another world ;-), 
the problem is that I have no control over the source system, only a read access to the tables

Comment: External tables aren't the only way to reference data in Oracle from SQL. What are your actual constraints? Do you have to use the `my_oracle_ds` data source? Do you have Oracle connection details and login credentials?

Comment: My idea was to use Polybase in SQL Server 2019 to avoid moving data with some kind of tool (SSIS, dbt etc). 
Oracle is not the only source so I hoped to create a "virtual" landing zone for all source data with one way (external tables) to "load" data from sources.
I could config a linked server to the Oracle database but hoped not having to do that.

Comment: I don’t know that there is much difference between a linked server and a poly base external table in this case. You’re talking about federated data, which is not a new idea. What do the Oracle DBAs think of adhoc queries on their database?

Comment: It should be used for nightly batch loads from Oracle so the DBA is ok with that.
We would not let users running wild with adhoc queries round the clock, it's a controlled batch load to a data warehouse.

Comment: If it’s a batch load then that actually makes an ETL process a lot more suitable for this.

Comment: The ETL tool could something as simple (and reliable) as flat files and BCP

Comment: Yes, that is what we have (flat files and bcp). It is simple, reliable and fast but the flat files have limitations (large text columns with new lines etc) and one idea to overcome those limitations was Polybase.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYSCHEMA.MY_EXT_TABLE
(
    SOMECOL NVARCHAR(21) COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_BIN,
    SOME_DATETIME DATETIME2,    
    SOME_DATE_COMM DATE,
    SOME_FLOAT FLOAT,
    SOME_TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('America/Los_Angeles', 'TZR') 
) WITH ( LOCATION = N'ORACLEDATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE' , DATA_SOURCE = my_oracle_ds ) GO
```

Comment: `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` is an Oracle function. This is SQL 2019